# Remove duplicated rows based on two columns of type "character" in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and want to remove rows that have duplicated strings in two columns (named "Up" & "Down"). If some rows have duplicated string values in only 1 of the 2 columns then they should not be removed. From the duplicated rows I would like to keep the one with the highest value found on another column (named "Fold"). Apart from this task, a 4th column (named "Name") also requires some character substitutions as follows:

From this:

```
ID  Name                    Fold   Up           Down
1   mRNA_splicing(5)        3.2    a,b,c,d,e    f,g,h,i 
2   mRNA_processing(7)      3.1    a,b,c,d,e    f,g,h,i 
3   adherens_junctions(5)   2.6    k,l,m        p,q,r,s,t,u
4   glucose_transport(4)    3.4    d,j,n        o,p,v,w,z              
5   hexose_transport(2)     3.5    d,j,n        o,p,v,w,y,z
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
ID  Name                    Fold   Up           Down
1   mRNA splicing           3.2    a,b,c,d,e    f,g,h,i  
2   adherens junctions      2.6    k,l,m        p,q,r,s,t,u
3   glucose transport       3.4    d,j,n        o,p,v,w,z              
4   hexose transport        3.5    d,j,n        o,p,v,w,y,z
```

Regarding functions that perform removal of duplicated rows, neither `duplicate` nor `unique` works for characters, so what to do here? I appreciate your elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a data table solution:

```
dt <- as.data.table(your_df)
dt <- dt[dt[, .I[Fold == max(Fold)], by=list(Up, Down)]$V1]
dt[["Name"]] <- gsub("_", " ", sub("\\(.*?\\)$", "", dt[["Name"]]))
dt

   ID               Name Fold        Up        Down
1:  1      mRNA splicing  3.2 a,b,c,d,e     f,g,h,i
2:  3 adherens junctions  2.6     k,l,m p,q,r,s,t,u
3:  4  glucose transport  3.4     d,j,n   o,p,v,w,z
4:  5   hexose transport  3.5     d,j,n o,p,v,w,y,z
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution in `base R`:

```
df <- df[order(df$Fold, decreasing = TRUE),]
df <- df[!(duplicated(df$Up) & duplicated(df$Down)),]
df$Name <- gsub("_", " ", gsub('.{0,3}$', '', df$Name))
df <- df[order(df$ID),]
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ID  Name                    Fold   Up           Down
1   mRNA_splicing(5)        3.2    a,b,c,d,e    f,g,h,i 
                 2   mRNA_processing(7)      3.1    a,b,c,d,e    f,g,h,i 
                 3   adherens_junctions(5)   2.6    k,l,m        p,q,r,s,t,u
                 4   glucose_transport(4)    3.4    d,j,n        o,p,v,w,z              
                 5   hexose_transport(2)     3.5    d,j,n        o,p,v,w,y,z
                 ", header = TRUE)

df$Name <- as.character(df$Name)
```

**Output**

```
   ID           Name    Fold        Up        Down
1  1      mRNA splicing  3.2 a,b,c,d,e     f,g,h,i
3  3 adherens junctions  2.6     k,l,m p,q,r,s,t,u
4  4  glucose transport  3.4     d,j,n   o,p,v,w,z
5  5   hexose transport  3.5     d,j,n o,p,v,w,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` + `stringr` (*edited to incorporate tmfmnk's suggestion*):

```r
df %>% 
    group_by(Up, Down) %>% 
    slice(which.max(Fold)) %>% 
    mutate(Name = str_remove(Name, "\\(.*?\\)"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Up, Down [4]
     ID Name                Fold Up        Down       
  <int> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      
1     1 mRNA_splicing        3.2 a,b,c,d,e f,g,h,i    
2     5 hexose_transport     3.5 d,j,n     o,p,v,w,y,z
3     4 glucose_transport    3.4 d,j,n     o,p,v,w,z  
4     3 adherens_junctions   2.6 k,l,m     p,q,r,s,t,u
```

Comment: Or maybe just `df %>%
 group_by(Up, Down) %>%
 slice(which.max(Fold))`.

Comment: Good call @tmfmnk, I've added your version.